# Javascript & Firebase: How to switch Google account

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication

I'm using `firebase.auth().signOut()` to log a user out of his Google account. However, when I the user logs in again using `firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)` (`const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()`), he immediately gets logged in to the Google account he was last logged in with. No password request, no UI, nothing. Just a short loading animation and the user is logged in again.

What do I have to do so the user can switch to a different Google account? At the moment it's simply not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little late response but hope it helps.

You can add a custom parameter to the auth provider to force picking an account each time.

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
  prompt: 'select_account'
});
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
```